# Why quaternion need to be conjugated first before conversion to rotation matrix?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Stephan,

I am following the tutorial, but I have one thing that I still don't understand:
Why quaternion need to be conjugated first before conversion to rotation matrix?
For example in pose_sensor.cpp inside ssf_updates:
C_wv = state_old.q_wv_.conjugate().toRotationMatrix();
Why it's not just:
C_wv = state_old.q_wv_.toRotationMatrix();

I thought quarternion q_wv_ is already in the same reference frame as C_wv, as its name suggests???

Please give me some lights. Thanks a lot!

Best Regards,

Giovanni

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174861/why-quaternion-need-to-be-conjugated-first-before-conversion-to-rotation-matrix?/) by [giovanni.sutanto](https://answers.ros.org/users/18909/giovanni.sutanto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Folks,

I eventually contacted Stephan Weiss personally thru e-mail. This is his respond:
"The naming of the variables is not very consistent, unfortunately. q_wv should be q_vw, hence the confusion."

Hope this helps!

Cheers,

Giovanni

---

Originally posted by [giovanni.sutanto](https://answers.ros.org/users/18909/giovanni.sutanto/) with karma: 56 on 2014-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2